# Google colab can't read csv file though I entered correct path

Tags: python, csv, google-colaboratory

I tried to get genres of songs in [regional-us-daily-latest](https://spotifycharts.com/regional/us/daily/latest), and output genres and other datas as csv file. But colab said,

`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'regional-us-daily-latest.csv'`

I mounted My Drive, but still didn't work.
Could you shed some light on this?

```
!pip3 install spotipy

import pandas as pd
import spotipy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyClientCredentials
import json
from google.colab import drive

client_id = ‘ID’
client_secret = ’SECRET’
client_credentials_manager = spotipy.oauth2.SpotifyClientCredentials(client_id, client_secret)
spotify = spotipy.Spotify(client_credentials_manager=client_credentials_manager)

import csv
csvfile = open('/content/drive/MyDrive/regional-us-daily-latest.csv', encoding='utf-8')
csvreader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)

us = ("regional-us-daily-latest.csv", "us.csv")

for region in (us):
  inputfile = region[0]
  outputfile = region[1]
  songs = pd.read_csv(inputfile, index_col=0, header=1)
  songs = songs.assign(Genre=0)
  for index, row in songs.iterrows():
    artist = row["Artist"]
    result = spotify.search(artist, limit=1, type="artist")
    genre = result["artists"]["items"][0]["genres"]
    songs['Genre'][index] = genre
  songs.head(10)
  songs.to_csv(outputfile)
  files.download(outputfile)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. please mount the drive first

   ```
        from google.colab import drive
        drive.mount('/content/drive')
   ```
2. Change the directory to MyDrive and check current directory

   ```
        import os
        os.chdir("drive/My Drive/")
        print(os.getcwd())
        !ls
   ```
3. Set the path of file. and use **source_file** variable where file name required

   ```
   source_file = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "regional-us-daily-latest.csv")
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I tried as you said, and it worked the first time, but after the second time, I got this error.```FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'r'``` Can you please tell me what is causing this error?

Comment: you just need mount and change directory for the first time in second case comment them

Answer (score 0):

Save the csv file in the Google drive  and go to your notebook click on drive and search for your file in the drive . Then copy the path of the csv  file in a variable and use the variable using read_csv()  method